# Return year count even when count is 0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, charts, eloquent

I'm trying to work on a chart with a few datasets, however for the purposes of asking this question, I will only include one.

At the moment if I have the following in my controller:

```
$maintenancesForklifts =
    DB::table("equipment_attachments")
                            ->join('equipment as equip', 'equip.id', '=', 'equipment_attachments.unitID')
                            ->select(DB::raw('year(date) as year'), DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
                            ->where('attachmentCategory','Maintenance')
                            ->where('equip.unit_type',3)
                            ->orderBy(DB::raw("year(date)"))
                            ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(date)"))
                            ->get();
```

I will get this returned:

```
[{"year":2005,"count":2},{"year":2006,"count":2},{"year":2010,"count":4},{"year":2011,"count":1},{"year":2012,"count":2},{"year":2013,"count":1},{"year":2014,"count":10},{"year":2015,"count":7},{"year":2016,"count":6},{"year":2017,"count":19},{"year":2018,"count":4}]
```

As you can see there are a few years missing if I went from say 2000 to the present day. Do you know how I could return the results so that they would come back with the years that have a zero count?

Comment: Are you wanting a db specific way or are you happy with filling in the years after you've got the data from the db?

Comment: Does the join have a relation with the date?

Comment: @RossWilson - I am okay with either, though I would prefer a db way to make it sustainable. But again, I don't really care at the moment so long as I can get it to work

Comment: @undrftd - No, the date is only on the table `equipment_attachments`, and doesn't have anything to do with the join

Comment: Do you have a beginning year?

Comment: @RossWilson - At the moment, I'll be happy with 2000.

Comment: Lastly, what version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.6 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this:

```
$years = collect(range(2000, now()->format('Y')))->map(function ($year) use ($maintenancesForklifts) {
    return $maintenancesForklifts->firstWhere('year', $year) ?? (object)['year' => $year, 'count' => 0];
});
```

Comment: Where would you suggest putting this in the code as related above? Thanks!